# Cannot update column in SQL

Tags: sql

```
UPDATE SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME SET NAME='JOHN' WHERE ID=999;
```

When I run this query it is showing

> Invalid SQL query

What is the wrong in this SQL query?
I want to run this query using schema name.

Comment: Question updated

Comment: try putting brackets 
UPDATE [SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME] SET [NAME]='JOHN' WHERE [ID]=999;

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Which tool do you use to run the SQL query? And which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: The statement is fine: https://rextester.com/YKTE23303

Comment: schema_name is what.... is this is exactly your database name

Comment: The SQL Validator says: **Conforms to Core SQL-99**. (https://developer.mimer.com/services/sql-validator-99/)

Comment: Thy syntax is just fine. Does the table exists, having those columns? And you have UPDATE privilege to it as well? Any constraints or triggers`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this for SQL Server

```
UPDATE [SCHEMA_NAME].[dbo].[TABLE_NAME] SET NAME='JOHN' WHERE ID=999;
```

For MYSQL

```
 UPDATE  `SCHEMA_NAME`.`TABLE_NAME` SET `NAME`=0
```

Comment: How do you know this question is for SQL Server? If the OP hasn't provided enough information (like what database system they are using), then you shouldn't answer, but ask for clarification in the comments.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: actually I am not using mysql, so posted my ans for `sql server` directly, now added for `mysql` too.

Comment: Again, how do you know the OP is using MySQL? Guesses aren't good answers.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: then I think it is better to flag this question for closed or some relevant action rather then arguing on answer posted on the question.... lolzz